# IMAP Push Notification All Accounts

Tags: ruby, linux, email, imap

I have an IMAP email server with 1000's of accounts and an Rails app server. I need the email server to send a notification to the app server if an email is received by any of the users on the email server so that the app server can pull the email.

I have heard of IMAP IDLE but I prefer not to create so many active connections to the mail serve. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you control the SMTP server itself, you can invent some protocol for it to notify your rails app server.  Nearly all SMTP servers have some sort of way to run a script on each mail reception.

Comment: I am using Postfix right now. Any idea where to start to write the protocol?

Comment: How about using the info in the Postfix log to tell you when a message has been delivered to a user?  If you need the delivery notification in near-realtime then 'tail' the log to grab the info.